# Is there a way to remove extra space when using qtree?

Tags: spacing, brackets, qtree

Is there a way to remove the extra space in the example below? (That is, to make the square brackets smaller but in such a way that the whole tree still falls within the brackets)

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=4.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{stmaryrd, sfmath, tikz, tikz-cd, qtree, pifont,gb4e}

\begin{document}
\left\llbracket \Tree[ \textbf{blah} [ blah [ \textbf{blah} [ \textbf{blah} [ \textbf{blah} [ \textbf{blah} \textbf{blah} ] ] ] ] ] ] \right\rrbracket
\end{document}
```

---

```
\begin{flalign*}
  & \left\llbracket \Tree[ \textbf{blah} [ blah [ \textbf{blah} [ \textbf{blah} [ \textbf{blah} \textbf{blah} ] ] ] ] ] \right\rrbracket^a=  & \eqno{Explanation}\\
  & [\lambda x. \left\llbracket \Tree[ blah [ \textbf{blah} [ \textbf{blah}  [ \textbf{of} \textbf{Joe} ] ] ] ] \right\rrbracket^{a}]=  & \eqno{Explanation} &\\
  & [\lambda x. \left\llbracket \Tree[  \textbf{is} [ \textbf{blah} [ \textbf{blah} \textbf{blah} ] ] ]  \right\rrbracket^{a}(\llbracket blah\rrbracket^{a})]=  & \eqno{Explanation}  & \\
\end{flalign*}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! Yes, there is.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=4.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd}

\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{sfmath}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\[
\left\llbracket \vcenter{\hbox{\Tree[ \textbf{blah} [ blah [ \textbf{blah} [
\textbf{blah} [ \textbf{blah} [ \textbf{blah} \textbf{blah} ] ] ] ] ] ]}} \right\rrbracket
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, when removing the unused white space, somehow also some of the unused packages disappeared. ;-)

**UPDATE**: As for the additional piece of your question: it works the same way: just wrap the `\Tree[...]` into `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=4.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd}

\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{sfmath}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
  & \left\llbracket \vcenter{\hbox{\Tree[ \textbf{blah} [ blah [ \textbf{blah} [
  \textbf{blah} [ \textbf{blah} \textbf{blah} ] ] ] ] ]}} \right\rrbracket^a=  & 
  \tag{\text{Explanation}}\\
  & [\lambda x. \left\llbracket \vcenter{\hbox{\Tree[ blah [ \textbf{blah} [
  \textbf{blah}  [ \textbf{of} \textbf{Joe} ] ] ] ]}} \right\rrbracket^{a}]=  & 
  \tag{\text{Explanation}} &\\
  & [\lambda x. \left\llbracket \vcenter{\hbox{\Tree[  \textbf{is} [
  \textbf{blah} [ \textbf{blah} \textbf{blah} ] ] ]}}  \right\rrbracket^{a}(\llbracket blah\rrbracket^{a})]=  & \tag{\text{Explanation}}  & \\
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I only couldn't run your code because it didn't like `\eqno`, which I never saw before. So I replaced it by something which might do what it should do. (It could well be that I removed the package that contains `\eqno`, if so, sorry, but the solution won't depend on this.)

Comment: Thanks! What if I want to use this "bracketed tree" inside flalign for example? Then `\[ ... \]` doesn't work anymore. Or should I post it as a separate question?

Comment: @user181940 Absolutely. Just do `\begin{flalign}
\left\llbracket \vcenter{\hbox{\Tree[ \textbf{blah} [ blah [ \textbf{blah} [
\textbf{blah} [ \textbf{blah} [ \textbf{blah} \textbf{blah} ] ] ] ] ] ]}} \right\rrbracket
\end{flalign}` i.e. without the `\[` and `\]`. You can use this in any math environment, I just added one because you had none.

Comment: It only seems to work with `\vcenter` :( The way I use flalign is as to meet the needs of my previous question. (I've just added a code above.) Is there a way to remove extra space in that case? (Or in the case of your answer to my previous question.)

Comment: @user181940 It does work the same way. Just wrap `\Tree[...]` into `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}`. I modified my answer accordingly. Please consider only loading the packages that are really needed because otherwise it is hard to write an answer that serves everyone.